# spring-kafka: DefaultErrorHandler with DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(BiFunction) not considered. No DL topic created

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In my Spring Boot application using `spring-kafka`, I am trying to configure an error handler with 2 things:-

- Retry message consumption failures a certain times (`FixedBackOff`) before publishing to a dead letter topic
- Create a dead letter topic with a name of my choice

Using

```
// Version highlights
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
...
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka' // 2.8.8
```

Here is the code I am using based on what I read in Spring docs and reiterated in several articles online:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultErrorHandler byteArrayDefaultErrorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template) {
  var recoverer =
    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(
      template,
      (record, e) -> new TopicPartition("%s.deadLetter".formatted(record.topic()), 0);
    );

  return new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer, new FixedBackOff(3000, 3));
}
```

**But** the above bean is not considered/used. So, when consumption encounters a failure (currently simulating failure by throwing an exception),

- the `FixedBackOff` is not considered but the default one with 10 attempts back to back is used.
- No DL topic is created.

Currently, the consumer config class has minimal stuff:

```java
@Bean public ConsumerFactory<String, byte[]> byteArrayConsumerFactory() { ... }

@Bean public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> byteArrayListenerContainerFactory() { .. }

@Bean public DefaultErrorHandler byteArrayDefaultErrorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template) { ...code pasted above... }
```

And the listener is as follows:

```java
@KafkaListener(
 topics = "${app.config.kafka.topic}",
 containerFactory = "byteArrayListenerContainerFactory"
)
public void consumeMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) { ... }
```

Am at a loss figuring out what I have missed or added something conflicting the wiring. Help figuring out is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error handler bean will only be wired in by boot if you are using Boot's auto configured container factory.

Since you are creating your own container factory bean...

```
@Bean public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> byteArrayListenerContainerFactory() { .. }
```

...you must add the error handler yourself - see `setCommonErrorHandler()`.

The framework does not automatically provision the dead letter topic; add a `@Bean NewTopic dlt() { ... }`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#configuring-topics

Comment: Ahh I see .. For some reason Spring would be built these parts in pieces based on which beans are available. Thanks. Will try and report back.